# In PHP, can a non-anonymous function inherit variables from the parent scope?

Tags: php, scope

I am writing a basic plugin system in PHP. I *have* researched Decorators and Observers.

To keep the learning curve small, I would like to simply be able to write, in key places, `hook($someHookNumber)` (passing no other arguments) and have it be replaced by some corresponding code that **shares the same variable scope**, as if I had just simply `include`'d the code.

At the moment, `hook(1)` runs any functions that have registered for the calling method (and class) at the given hook number (in this case, 1.) So, scope is at least two functions below the method that called `hook()`.

While member variables like `$this->exampleVariable` can be manipulated perfectly fine two functions down (if called by an object,) any non-member variables like `$text` are only manipulated within the scope of the plugin function.

The easy solution is "just use member variables" or "use globals," but I'd rather `hook()` work as similar to `include()` as possible to avoid future headaches.

Comment: Read about `dependency injection` in php and try to avoid using global functions within class scope.

Comment: Anonymous functions can use the `use()` directive to inherit variables from the containing. But this doesn't work for named functions.

Comment: Or pass arguments by refrence, like `function hook(&$someHookNumber){}` too manipulate the variable

Comment: All good ideas. Unfortunately, I think it would end up too unwieldy to pass all the references needed every time, considering I don't know what variables a plugin may need.

Comment: `I don't know what variables a plugin may need` if you store/handel all your [global] variables and instances with a dependency injection container, you have only have to pass the container once. Thing more from class scope instead of global scope.

Comment: I may have oversimplified my question (`hook()` is actually not a global function, but a method in a Plugin class, for one.) I have zero global variables at the moment, I'm just trying to make sure any temporary variables contained in a method are accessible to plugins. I may be trying to add too much sugar by avoiding passing the variables. I appreciate the idea of a container, though.